# Is it possible to use symbolic breakpoints with ARKit?

Tags: xcode, arkit

I'm trying to add symbolic breakpoints in Xcode to debug an `ARAnchor` subclass named `ItemAnchor` I'm using that has a property named `itemScaleX`. For some reason the breakpoint doesn't get triggered.

I've tried to add a new symbolic breakpoint with the symbols `-[ItemAnchor setItemScaleX]`, `-[ItemAnchor itemScaleX]`, and just `-[ItemAnchor]`. None of them works. I even tried the symbol `-[ARAnchor setTransform]`, `-[ARAnchor transform]`, `-[ARAnchor]`, and many other combinations. None of them work triggers even thought I know they are being initialized and their properties set.

When I'm writing the symbol, the autocomplete works and suggests classes and properties in my project.

[image]

I'm expecting the symbolic breakpoints to work, but for some reason they don't. does Xcode actually support symbolic breakpoints for ARKit debugging? Using the same method with other classes such as `SCNNode` with the symbol `-[SCNNode scale]` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Swift, you may want to put breakpoints on `ItemAnchor.itemOrientationX`, for example, since it should use Swift syntax (as opposed to the Obj-C syntax).